# Removing crawing from search engine on my login page

Tags: robots.txt

I have a login page (login.aspx) that is currently indexed in google when somebody does a search.

I have created a robots.txt file with the following:

```
    User-agent: *
    Disallow: /login.aspx
```

My question is how long will it take effect to where my login.aspx page will no longer be indexed by google. Is there anything else necessary to tell Google not to index my login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could take up to 90 days before the index is removed from google database but realistic a week or two to update. You could also ask google to remove that page on Webmaster Tools but will work the same way as the crawler.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to log in to Google Webmaster tools and use the "Remove URL" feature from Site Configuration/crawler access and also increase the crawling speed from Site Configuration/Settings . This might help accelerate the removal of the URL.